# How to call an async method from another method

Tags: c#, async-await

I am having a difficult time calling an async method from my current method.
Trying to do something like this:

```
int i;
public void Method1() {
    while (statement1) {
        ~code~
        Method2(i);
    }
    while (statement2) {
        ~code~
        Method2(i);
    }
}

public async void Method2(int i) {
    if(statement){
        ~code~
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
    else
    {
        ~code~
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```

So i want basically `Method2` to be a method for controlling the flow (uses another method which changes pictures in pictureboxes), but I can't get it to work and when it works it never delays anything. Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?
`Method2` changes `Method1`'s while statements eventually.

Comment: a) Does Method1 have to wait for Method2 to finish before it proceeds? b) Can you make Method1 async as well? c) Don't use async void, use async Task

Comment: Please post [MCVE] - "Method2 changes Method1's while statements eventually" is not enough to see what is going on.

Comment: `async` does not mean "execute in the background". It means "give me a promise to execute this later that I can `await`" (and do some other stuff with). Depending on what, exactly, you're trying to achieve, multiple approaches to rewriting this are possible. Why is `Method2` async to start with, again?

Comment: a) Yes that's exactly what i want.

Method2 modifies one of two variables that are in while's statement, when that's done Method1 continues to the second while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [best practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for async/await is to use async "all the way down" (unless you really and truly don't care about Method1 waiting for Method2 to complete).

It's possible to mix Task.Wait (or similar constructs) with async code, but it's a [bad idea](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) because it can lead to deadlocks.

The best thing here would be, as others have indicated, just make Method1 async too:

```
public async Task Method1() {
while (statement1) {
    await Method2(i);
    // ...
}
```

Note that you'll have to make Method1 return a Task too because otherwise you can't wait it:

```
public async Task Method2
```

This may be a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though because there's no reason for the code sample you provide to be async in the first place (or even a separate method, for that matter) - you can just do Thread.Sleep instead. Also, the "if" statement is pointless because, based on what you've shown us, you delay for 2 seconds either way. It would be helpful if you could show a more substantial code sample so we can get a better sense of what you're trying to do so we can recommend whether async is even an appropriate solution here.

One final point: one of the purposes of async/await is to allow the calling thread to do other work while it's waiting for a result - for example, if you want to download a file without "hanging" the UI. I've seen plenty of cases where people use async/await in a way that essentially obviates the purpose though. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
     // This is a terrible thing to do but it's for illustration purposes
     Task task = Method1();
     task.Wait();

     // Some other work
 }

 private static async Task Method1() {
     await Method2();
     // Some other work
 }

 private static async Task Method2() {
     await Method3();
     // Some other work
 }

 private static async Task Method3() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
 }
```

This is a pretty dumb illustration, granted, but in this case the async/await is completely pointless because it's just doing each action sequentially anyway.

Comment: As i said, Method2 is used for animation and changing between pictureboxes. I want the delay either way, but the "way" of changing the pictures is defined by the if's in method 2 and theres way too much code there i didn't want you guys to be confused. Can't understand the downvotes though.

Comment: @supItsMe I didn't downvote but it would probably be helpful to put that information in the question itself for the purpose of clarity (because it's unclear from the original question why you're doing async in the first place; it's always better to include some kind of a description of what you're trying to accomplish in the question itself).

Answer (score 0):

You should make `Method1` also asyncronous and add await operator for `Method2` call:

```
public async Task Method1() {
    while (statement1) {
        ~code~
        await Method2(i);
    }
    while (statement2) {
        ~code~
        await Method2(i);
    }
}

public async Task Method2(int i) {
    if(statement){
        ~code~
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
    else
    {
        ~code~
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```

If you need Method1 to be syncronous for some reason, you should call Wait() on task returned from Method2. However it's considered as bad practice because you loose advantage of .NET thread pool.

Comment: "Can not await void Method".

Comment: Change return type of Method2() to Task: public async Task Method2(int i)

Comment: Do i have to return something in Method2 in order for Method1 to continue executing?
Also, can i modify global data in Method2?

Comment: @supItsMe You have to declare the return type as Task in the method signature but you don't have to have an explicit return statement at any point - the compiler does some "magic" in the background to take care of that for you. It *is* possible to modify external state from an async method, but you have to be careful about how you do it to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

For another method to be able to await Method2 the latter must return have a return type of Task or Task (and not void):

```
public async Task Method2(int i) {
if(statement){
    ~code~
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}
else
{
    ~code~
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}
```

Method1 should then be marked as async and await Method2:

```
public async void Method1() {
while (statement1) {
    ~code~
    await Method2(i);
}
while (statement2) {
    ~code~
    await Method2(i);
}
}
```